# Do the &= and |= operators for bool short-circuit?

Tags: c++, boolean, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting, compound-assignment

When writing code like this in C++:

```
bool allTrue = true;
allTrue = allTrue && check_foo();
allTrue = allTrue && check_bar();
```

`check_bar()` will not be evaluated if `check_foo()` returned `false`. This is called [short-circuiting or short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and is part of the lazy evaluation principle.

Does this work with the compound assignment operator `&=`?

```
bool allTrue = true;
allTrue &= check_foo();
allTrue &= check_bar(); //what now?
```

*For logical `OR` replace all `&` with `|` and `true` with `false`.*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ok, I changed my formulation a bit. It seems that lazy evaluation just means to skip evaluation of parts of the program if you don't need them, as in regular if-else-clauses. Short-circuiting is taking it a step further, but seems to follow the same basic thought.

Comment: @Mehrdad after reading the answers, I agree with you. There seems to be absolutely no reason whatsoever for C++ to not have a &&= assignment operator.

Comment: Is there a missing word in the title?

Comment: @n.1 no? short-circuit is a verb in this case.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know it was a verb.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

From C++11 `5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators`:

> The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is evaluated only once.

However, you're mixing up logical AND which *does* short-circuit, and the bitwise AND which never does.

The text snippet `&&=`, which would be how you would do what you're asking about, is *nowhere* to be found in the standard. The reason for that is that it doesn't actually exist: there is no logical-and-assignment operator.

Comment: My fault, it was probably just wishful thinking. Do you know of a specific reason why C++ doesn't have a `&&=` operator?

Comment: @iFreilicht: any _specific_ reason? Probably because C never had it and the original C++ compiler was more or less just a front end for C, meant to be "C with classes", not "C with classes and a couple of extra operators" :-)

Comment: @paxdiabla soooo why didn't C have it? I mean it surely seems like a useful thing to me and it wouldn't be too hard to implement either.

Comment: @iFreilicht, C didn't have it because Dennis Ritchie obviously _didn't_ feel it was useful (we could ask him directly if he hadn't shuffled off this mortal coil, leaving many of us the lesser for it). ANSI C didn't have it because their mandate was to codify existing practice rather than create a new language. ISO didn't have it because they basically rubber-stamped ANSI (not in a bad way). It's not been added to C since then because it either hasn't been put forward as a proposal or it has and it didn't garner enough votes. I don't think I can provide more detail than that :-)

Comment: @paxdiabla You certainly don't have to, thanks for your precise answer!

Comment: @iFreilicht: There aren't a whole lot of cases where `x &&= y;` would be useful.  If `x` and `y` are both known to be zero or one, then `if (x) x=y;` would be more efficient [actually, I wish `x && y` had been defined to yield `y` if `x` was non-zero, but it's decades too late for that].

Comment: @supercat I came with a question and I think that's the answer - I was trying `x = (y / z) || 1;` hoping that it would give me `y / z` if `y >= z`, but in the case that it isn't, I don't want `0`, I want `1`. And you're saying something like that isn't doable (extrapolating from your example about `x && y`)?

Comment: @dwanderson: Yeah.  I think it's really a shame that the operators were defined as they are; I'm hard-pressed to think of cases where C's behavior for && and || is more useful than would be x?y:0 or x:y:x [but only evaluating x once] but there are many cases where the alternatives would be more useful, and of course a huge number of cases where either would have the same practical effect.

Comment: @supercat: `if(x) x=y` is definitively not more efficient than a supposed `x &&=y`: `If` jump and so invalidate all the pipeline of the processor, which could easily slow-down the operation by several cycles. also, your statement is 8 letters, while the other is 5 letters. Personally I use some kind of  `x = x&&y` very often, and when x has a long name, this construction make a significant readability difference.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: On many processors, evaluation of "x&&=y;" would require something like "load 0; test x; branch if zero to Q; test y; branch if zero to Q; load 1; Q: store x" while "if (x) x=y;" would require "test x; branch if zero to Q; load y; store x; Q:", and "x ?y:0" would require "load zero; test x; branch if zero to Q; load y; Q: store X".  Only on processors with an instruction to conditionally load a register with 0 or 1 does "&&=" behave respectably.

Comment: You are right, although, clang make the same result as using `if(x) x=y`. IMO, a better solution could be achieved without jumping as soon as both booleans have a normalized representation.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: If the Booleans are known to have a normalized representation, then more efficient code is possible.  My point is that I think || and && would have been more helpful if they require that operand types be compatible but did not normalize operands to integer 0 and integer 1.  Having to use `!!x` in the rare cases where normalization is required would have been a small burden compared to all the cases where normalization would be more expensive or semantically less helpful than passing through values.

Answer (score 17):

No, they do not cut-short.

Note that the `&=` and `|=` operators are formed as `&`+`=` and `|`+`=`. **Bit operators** `&` and `|` do not perform shortcut evaluation.

Only **boolean operators** `&&` and `||` perform it.

This means that a short-cutting operator would have to be traditionally named `&&=` and `||=`. Some languages provide them. C/C++ does not.

Answer (score 14):

The short-circuit (i.e. lazy) evaluation is only for logical `&&` and `||`. Bitwise `&` and `|` evaluate both arguments.

Answer (score 7):

First: `a &= b;` is not the same as `a = a && b;`. `a &= b;` means `a = a & b;`. In C/C++ there is no `a &&= b;`.

Logical AND `a && b` is bit like a test for 1 bit. If the first "bit" is already 0, than the result will always be 0 no matter the second. So it is not necessary to evaluate `b` if the result is already clear from `a`. The C/C++ standard allows this optimization.

Bitwise AND `a & b` performs this test for all bits of `a` and `b`. So `b` needs to be evaluated if at least one bit in `a` would be non-zero. You could perhaps wish that if `a==0`, than `b` would not be evaluated, but this optimization is not allowed in C/C++.

Answer (score 5):

The code `allTrue &= check_foo();` is equivalent to `allTrue = allTrue & check_foo()`
In which you are using `bitwise AND` and no lazy evaluation is performed.

The `bitwise AND` must take two arguments who's binary representation has the same length, and uses`logical AND` operation to compare each corresponding pair of bits.

Comment: Pretty sure you can use `&` and `|` with integer promotion, ie. `uint16_t x = 0xabcd; uint8_t y = 0xef; uint16_t z = x | y; // z = 0xabef`, so saying it's required that "binary representation has the same length" isn't true?

Answer (score 2):

Since & is a bit operation, check_foo()` will be evaluated irrespective of value of result

```
result = false;
result &= check_foo(); // check_foo() is needless called
```

However, `check_foo()` will not be called if you use `&&` and `result` is `false` as in:

```
result = false;
result = result && check_foo(); // check_foo() is not called, the bitwise operator shortcircuits
```